# Ruby on rails Validation does not work for Form objects that contain Action text, etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

## Error Overview

There is a Github URL of a simple app that reproduces the problem in the bottom paragraph.

I'm creating an application that allows article submission. To make it easier to submit articles, I introduced Rails Action text. I also decided to add a tagging feature, so I have a tags table, an article table, and a user table in the database. The article form looks like the following image.
[The article form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sm862.png)

I was able to submit an article, but I wanted to check the validation of the condition that the article could not be submitted with a blank field, so I submitted it with a blank field, but I got the following error.
[NoMethodError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iro24.png)

I don't know how to solve this problem and I need your help.

## The relevant source code

This is the view file of the corresponding section.↓

```
<%= render "shared/header" %>
<%= form_with model: @article, url: articles_path, class:'form-wrap', local: true do |f| %>

<%= render 'shared/error_messages', model: f.object %>

  <div class='article-form'>
    <div class="title-field">
      <%= f.label :title,  "題名" %>
      <%= f.text_area :title, class:"input-title" %>
    </div>
    <div class="tag-field", id='tag-field'>
      <%= f.label :name, "タグ" %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, class:"input-tag" %>
    </div>
    <div class="content-field">
      <%= f.label :content, "記事本文" %>
      <%= f.rich_text_area :content %>
    </div>
    <div id="search-result">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="submit-post">
    <%= f.submit "Send", class: "submit-btn" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This is the controller code.↓

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create]
  def index
    @article = Article.all.order(created_at: :desc)
  end

  def new
    @article = ArticlesTag.new
  end

  def create
    @article = ArticlesTag.new(article_params)
    if @article.valid?
      @article.save
      return redirect_to root_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def search
    return nil if params[:keyword] == ""
    tag = Tag.where(['name LIKE ?', "%#{params[:keyword]}%"] )
    render json:{ keyword: tag }
  end

  private
  def article_params
    params.require(:articles_tag).permit(:title, :content, :name).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
  end
end
```

This is the code of the Article model.↓

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  has_rich_text :content
  belongs_to :user
  has_one_attached :image
  has_many :article_tags
  has_many :tags, through: :article_tag_relations

end
```

This is the code of The Tag model.　↓

```
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :article_tag_relations
  has_many :articles, through: :article_tag_relations
  validates :name, uniqueness: true
end
```

This is the intermediate model between The Tag model and The Article model.↓

```
class ArticleTagRelation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

This is the Form object class that collects the tags and articles tables.

```
class ArticlesTag

  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :title, :name, :content, :user_id

  with_options presence: true do
    validates :title
    validates :name
    validates :content
    validates :user_id
  end

  def save
    article = Article.create(title: title, content: content, user_id: user_id)
    tag = Tag.where(name: name).first_or_initialize
    tag.save

    ArticleTagRelation.create(article_id: article.id, tag_id: tag.id)
  end

end
```

## Database Status

[Action text table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36Ii0.jpg)

[Article Tag Relation table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsfXm.jpg)

[Article table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heQRj.png)

[Tag table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1v95u.png)

Please help me.

## A simple application that reproduces the error.

github URL

[A simple app that reproduce the error](https://github.com/TaisonTsukada/tagtweet.git)

Comment: Can you share a simple app to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @ Arun Kumar Mohan  Ok! I will create app to reproduce the issue. Please wait.

Comment: [A simple app to reproduce the issue](https://github.com/TaisonTsukada/tagtweet.git)

Comment: @ Arun Kumar Mohan  This Github URL is a simple app.

Answer (score 0):

This is the error you are getting

`` undefined method `body' for "":String ``

That says that it is trying to call the method `body` on an empty string.

Why is it trying to call that method? Because you wrote this:
`<%= f.rich_text_area :content %>`
So the form helper is expecting that `content` contains an instance of a `RichText` (https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionText/RichText.html)

However, `content` actually just contains an instance of String, because your ArticlesTag model does not declare that it `has_rich_text` (like your Articles Model does)

I note that your ArticlesTag model is not persisted. I am not sure how to use rich text with a model that is not persisted - I suspect it might not be possible.

Comment: Then do I need to validate from the front side?